# How do I get the selection bar in VLC's playlist to show what's being played?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Let's say I have 15 shows in the playlist.  I play the first one, and
the selection bar is on the first show.  That's how it should be.  But
when it moves on to the remaining videos, the selection bar (or whatever
it's actually called) is still on the first video, which is no longer
correct.

How do I fix that, so that it's on whatever's currently being played?
I've looked for options, checked out the playlist documentation for VLC,
and found nothing that even looks related.  Same for Playlist Options
(using all options, not just the simple options).

FWIW, I'm using VLC 3.0.11 in M$ Windows 10 (but this is also an issue
with older versions of VLC on my Linux system, too).

Thanks

Comment: The one currently playing should be in bold text. Selection is an "OS thing" the app isn't really in charge of.

Comment: No hint whatsoever about which one is playing.  The reason this matters is if, say, I load up an entire season of something, and am clearly not going to sit all day and binge watch it.  It would be nice to know, without having to keep track, which (watched) episodes to remove and have the next episode on top.

Comment: If you tap S to stop, then spacebar to start, it will pick up from where it left off. My only problem, on Mac, is that if you quit or reboot, it forgets where it was. Almost all other apps will remember where they were.